# Update happening before state change due to promise?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have this update function that is supposed to update the state and the view of the component whenever 'Update' button is clicked; however, it only starts to update after 'Update' button is clicked. Like, I have to click update then change the form inputs to see the change of the view.

```
Expectation: 

 Step 1: Change Form input then click 'Update' button
 Step 2: State and View changes

Reality/Issue:

 Step 1: In order to see the change, I have to click the 'Update' button first
 Step 2: Then I can change Form input and see the change in my view.
```

How do I make it that state and the view of the component is changed only after 'Update' button is clicked?

I found that Promises are asynchronous, so I tried adding call-backs, used async await, or moved orders of the codes around, but it still produced the same issue.

```
export class EducationPage extends React.Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        incomingClass: {...this.props.location.state.data},
        alert: {
            display: false
        }};
    this.updateEdu = this.updateEdu.bind(this);
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
}   

handleChange = (event) => {
    const target = event.target;
    const value =  target.value;
    const name = target.name;
    this.setState((prevState) => {
        let newState = {};
        let data = Object.assign({}, prevState.data);
        data[name] = value;
        newState.data = data;
        return newState;
    });
};

updateEdu = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    let newEdu = {...this.state.incomingClass};
    BackEndRestPromiseService.updateEdu(newEdu).then(data => { // Promise
        this.setState({
            incomingClass: data
        }, () => console.log(data));
    }).catch(e => {
    console.log(e);
        this.setState({
            error: "Error!"
        });
    });
}

render() {
return (
    <div>
        <Form onSubmit={e => this.updateEdu(e)}>
        <Button type="submit">Update</Button>
            <Form.Row>
                <Form.Group as={Col}>
                    <Form.Label>School</Form.Label>
                    <Form.Control id="school" name="school" placeholder="School" value={this.state.incomingClass.school || ""} onChange={this.handleChange}/>
                </Form.Group>

                <Form.Group as={Col}>
                    <Form.Label>Grade</Form.Label>
                    <Form.Control id="grade" name="grade" placeholder="Grade #" value={this.state.incomingClass.grade || ""} onChange={this.handleChange}/>
                </Form.Group>
            </Form.Row>
        </Form>
    </div>
)
}
```

Comment: Have you tried the `onkeyup` event? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/keyup_event

Comment: There's nothing wrong with your code, maybe you are noticing the delay in the HTTP response ?

Comment: You only show the code that updates `education`. Please also post the code that uses `education`.

Comment: Are you sure it isn't just updating when the response comes back and the promise resolves?

Comment: @ Iskandar Reza Razali I am not sure how an onkeyup event would help?

Comment: @Avin Kavish I do not see any delay in the HTTP response. I have to click update then change the form inputs.

Comment: @WillJenkins That could be the case; however, from my understanding, it is coming back with the response with new education then it updates the state?

Comment: If you press Update and do nothing for the next 5 minutes, what happens?

Comment: Have you considered using Async-Await for this?

Comment: @AnDrOiD I have added more code. Please let me know if you need more info.

Comment: In the callback for the promise you update `this.state.education` but don't use it  anywhere in your code.

Comment: @Pray I believe you are doing too much in your `handleChange` method. You could leverage lifeCycle components to be sure that the new state has changed. Moreover, why do you need to perform that check before changing the state?

Comment: @AvinKavish I clicked the 'update' button and waited; however, the view of my component did not change.

Comment: @AnDrOiD I am very sorry. It it not supposed to be *this.state.education*. *this.state.education* is supposed to be *this.state.incomingClass*.

Comment: @Mark Hey Mark, Yes; I have used async-await, but it produced the same result. I was just trying to simplify the code. Also, what do you mean perform that check?

Comment: Yeah. Suggest async-await before you added more code. I meant to say why do you need the previous state before changing the state. I see that `incomingClass ` is set to the value of the props you are passing in, does this mean that the fields will have values set when the page loads?

Comment: @Mark Yes, the fields will have values set when the page loads.

Comment: What is in this object `this.props.location.state.data`

Comment: It is the initialized data. It is basically an object with bunch of strings.

Answer (score 2):

I'm going to simplify some of your code to make it easier to debug.

```
handleChange = (event) => {
    const { name, value } = event.target;
    this.setState(prevState => 
      ({ incomingClass: { ...prevState.incomingClass, [name]: value } }));
};
```

What I noticed here is that you have no `data` property in you initial state, only `incomingClass`. but your handleChange method operates on `prevState.data`. Also `setState` supports partially updating state. So you don't have to get the full previous state and set it.

Also, there is no need to rebuild `incomingClass` before sending it to the server.

```
updateEdu = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    BackEndRestPromiseService.updateEdu(this.state.incomingClass)
     .then(data => this.setState({ incomingClass: data }))
     .then(() => console.log(data))
     .catch(e => { console.log(e); this.setState({ error: "Error!" }) });
}
```

Since you have already use class properties, there is no need to use a lambda here nor bind it.

```
<Form onSubmit={this.updateEdu}>
```

This is unnecessary since you are using class properties

```
this.updateEdu = this.updateEdu.bind(this);
this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
```